# Shelf Stable "Ganache"

Tags: substitutions, chocolate, storage

I'm baking something that I might end up sending on a very long trip. For this I would want to make ganache, but it may be in transit for as long as 10 days so I don't want to use cream.

If I do make these, the ganache would between sandwich cookies. What could I use for that, stable at varying temperatures, for as long as 10 days, possibly even longer?

Comment: Maybe use the filling from a vegan chocolate truffle recipe?

Comment: @RossRidge That's a thought...Google-fu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a ganache type filling if you used water, cocoa powder,chocolate chips, butter, and icing sugar. Adding all but the chocolate chips in a saucepan will create a chocolate like sauce. Thick and with body. Once everything has melted,and blended smoothly together, you add the chocolate chips with the heat off. let the residual heat melt them the rest of the way. Once cooled it can be sandwiched between cookies, cake topping, cupcake "frosting", eclair icing. It is a shelf stable "ganache" like filling I like to use. In terms of quantity, I use 1 Lb. butter, 4 cups icing sugar, 1 cup water, 1 cup cocoa powder, 2 cups chocolate chips. This is a very rough recipe as I do most of my pastry making/baking by feel. *Note...The more chips you add, the thicker the end results.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try coconut milk? Makes for a fairly stable dairy-free ganache that holds at room temperature!! Just make sure you don't break your chocolate with too much heat :) I usually go with a double boiler.